# Dynamically select table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a SSIS package that syncs data from source to destination Tables, however I am looking for a solution where whenever package runs it automatically select table from previous month i.e. (TableName-1).

for example <102019> at the end of tablename

I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Chaitanya could you check my answer and let me know is your query resolve,please vote if you satisfied with my solution

Answer (score 1):

The "easiest" way would be the inject the value safely into your SQL. Assuming your calculating the value of TableName in SSIS, so you could do something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(?);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

SSIS packages can be very different (the answer depends on how you load your table).

In SSIS in you use Expressions, either on the Connection Manager or ExecuteSQLTask to apply dynamic behaviour. You can then calculate the tablename of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by previous month? Created in the previous month? That information is available in the table metadata. `select *
from sys.tables;` should give you a starting point. You can use a query against `create_date` to select your desired tables. Trying to place that into the table name is not a great approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `sql` query in `Execute SQl Task` and put the sql query infront of  `Sql statements` and set **resultset =Single row** after that go to `result set` tab and assign this value to a variable **table** and call that variable in `OLEDB destination connection manager`.

[image]
[image]

[image]